# Simplifying code without parent and children selectors

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".EditBusinessName").hide();

    $(".editBtn a").click(function() {      
        $(this).parent().parent('.myBusinessEdit').children('.EditBusinessName').show();
        $(this).hide();
    });

    $(".EditBusinessName a").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().parent(".EditBusinessName").hide();
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().children(".editBtn").children("a").show();
    });
});
```

How can I simplify the above code without using `parent()` and `children()` selectors? `div` class `myBusinessEdit` will be the common class for each sections.

http://plnkr.co/edit/xgP49K51urBvZQlyLGxQ?p=preview

Comment: Why do you not want to use `parent()` or `children()`? `closest()` and `find()` could work too, depending on your requirements.

Comment: There will be additional Divs once I use this static code in CMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic itself is quite sound, so there's not much simplification that could be done. You could certainly use `closest()` and `find()` to make the code less rigidly aligned to the number of parent/child elements in the HTML structure. Try this:

```js
$(".editBtn a").click(function() {
    $(this).hide().closest('.myBusinessEdit').find('.EditBusinessName').show();
});

$(".EditBusinessName a").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".EditBusinessName").hide();
    $(this).closest('.myBusinessEdit').find(".editBtn a").show();
});
```

```css
a {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
.EditBusinessName {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myBusinessEdit">
    <div class="editBtn"><a id="">Edit</a></div>
    <div class="EditBusinessName">
        <div class="">
            XBusinessName
            <a id="">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="myBusinessEdit">
    <div class="editBtn"><a id="">Edit</a></div>
    <div class="EditBusinessName">
        <div class="">
            XBusinessName
            <a id="">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="myBusinessEdit">
    <div class="editBtn"><a id="">Edit</a></div>
    <div class="EditBusinessName">
        <div class="">
            XBusinessName
            <a id="">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```